# Adding virtualhost to Apache prevent access to localhost

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, configuration, website, localhost

I am using Uubntu 16.04, with Apache2 (version 2.4) on my local personal laptop for development purpose.
I have added a virtual host (hehe) under sites-enabled directory.

Since I have added it, I have troubles accessing http://localhost from Firefox but not Chrome.

In Chrome, when accessing http://localhost I get the root web directory correctly and http://hehe brings me to the new virtualhost directory.

In Firefox accessing http://localhost brings me ALSO to the /hehe directory of the virtualhost.

Attached are the two files. Very strange, but it must be something in my virtualhost configuration.

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/xxx/myprojects/web

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /home/xxx/myprojects/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        #Allow from all
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Require ip ::1
</Directory>
```

001-hehe.conf

```
NameVirtualHost hehe:80
<VirtualHost hehe:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName hehe

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/xxx/myprojects/web/understandmydreams

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /home/xxx/myprojects/web/understandmydreams/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        #Allow from all
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Require ip ::1
</Directory>
```

Any idea how I can have **both localhost and a virtualhost** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that:

```
NameVirtualHost hehe:80
<VirtualHost hehe:80>
```

It's not doing the thing you are intending, but can cause hard-ish problems on future apache restarts (it introduces dependency on name resolution). It's very rarely used due to contrived implications.

You can and should declare a duplicate clause:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
```

followed by

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hehe
```

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the "ServerName" directive in 000-default.conf pointing to localhost.

As explained [Here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) It is best to always explicitly list a ServerName in every name-based virtual host.